# Storing value with line breaks in csv

Tags: python, webdriver

I grabbed an xpath that outputs data as follows:

```
Data1
Data2
Data3
Data4
```

I used `valueStore.storeCode(f"{test.splitlines()}")` and now the values are returned as `['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4']`in my CSV file. How can I have it stored as `Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4` in the CSV instead of how splitlines outputs it?

Comment: if you want to save csv file then better use module `csv` or `pandas` instead of creating manually lines.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

`test2 = test.splitlines()`
`listToStr = ','.join(map(str, test2))`

`listToStr` then returns `Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4`